# Why are my styles not loading with a angular4-webpack site

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

There are no errors.

I would have expected either the styles to  end up in vendor.css or as

My app.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app',
template: require('./app.component.html'),
styles:
 [
    "../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/south-street/theme.css",
    "../../../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    //...
],
```

})

My Webpack relevent line that mentions css:

```
  { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] }
```

And why does loading a style sheet have to  be so complicated.?

Comment: Do you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your Configure method in `Startup.cs`?  It is subtle makes you go nuts when its missing...

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `styleUrls[]` rather than `styles`

Comment: No styleUrls[] dosent work either. 

I just stuck old school link in _Layout.cshtml which sucks.

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />